# Scanf coordinates until EOF

Tags: c, scanf

I am having a quite interesting issue. I need to scan multiple coordinates in format `[x,y]` separated by ' ' until wild `EOF` appears. Then, i just need to end the while loop and proceed to the body of the function. I use this while loop for scanning 1 number at a time. Now, when I changed this to load 2 numbers at a time and modified the scanf input format to correspond with actual input, the scanning is OK until `EOF`, but instead of breaking the while loop, it waits for another input and doesn't leave the loop. And, if I try to add some numbers, it doesn't scan them although. I figured out that the only way to leave the loop is to put [ or [x or [x,on input and press enter, then it leaves the loop. If it succesfully scans 2 numbers, it won't end until I interrupt the application and shut it down.

```
while ( !feof(stdin) && (status=scanf("[%lf,%lf]",&x,&y))==2)
{   if (status==EOF)
            break;
    if (status != 2 && status != EOF)
            {printf("Wrong input.\n");
            free (X);
            free (Y);
            return 1;}
    X=(double*) realloc (X ,max * sizeof(*X));
    Y=(double*) realloc (Y ,max * sizeof(*Y));

    if ( X==NULL || Y==NULL)
            {free (X);
            free (Y);
            printf ("Allocation error.\n");
            return 1;}
    else
            {X[max-1]=x;
             Y[max-1]=y;
             max++;} 
    if (status != EOF)
            while (fgetc(stdin)!=' ') {}
}
```

I am not quite finished with this part of code by the meaning of wrong inputs etc. but this issue is worrying me much more atm. Thank you :)

Comment: remove the `!feof(stdin) && `. It is wrong and/or you don't need it. 2) the `(status=scanf("[%lf,%lf]",&x,&y))==2)` in the loop condition **guarantees** that status can only be 2 inside the loop; no need to test it, it will always be 2.

Comment: it makes no difference :/...i think there is problem with the format of the input I demand, but I can't figure out how to solve it

Comment: Of course it makes no difference, Your testing of the loop-invariant expression just indicates that you don't understand the (not)working of your program.

Comment: @wildplasser, exceptionally `!feof()` is not wrong here, it should be redundant according to the standard but isn't at least on Linux and Solaris (it is redundant on FreeBSD and NetBSD) when wanting to drive a program from the keyboard and the OP asked about that case in a previous question.

Comment: That why I said `and/or` you don't need it. That is _redundant_ in your wording. So I think we agree.

Comment: `while (fgetc(stdin)!=' ') {}` is a potential infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

**edit:** I misread the question - I was assuming that the input would be line by line:

```
[1.0,2.0]
[3.0,4.0]
...
```

The following code accepts inputs on the same line (or with newlines, it doesn't matter). If you are inputting manually you can break the loop with a `ctrl-d`.

```
bash-4.2$ ./a.out 
[1,2][3,4][5,6]
[7,8][9,0]
Values read in: # <--- I pressed ctrl-d on this line
[1.000000,2.000000]
[3.000000,4.000000]
[5.000000,6.000000]
[7.000000,8.000000]
[9.000000,0.000000]
```

Otherwise, something like this will work too:

```
bash-4.2$ echo "[1,2][3,4]" | ./a.out
Values read in:
[1.000000,2.000000]
[3.000000,4.000000]
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double * safe_realloc_double(double * ptr, size_t size);

int main()
{
    double x, y, *X = NULL, *Y = NULL;
    int max = 1, i;
    while (scanf(" [ %lf , %lf ]", &x, &y) == 2)
    {        
        X = safe_realloc_double(X, max);
        Y = safe_realloc_double(Y, max);
        if (X == NULL || Y == NULL)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            X[max-1]=x;
            Y[max-1]=y;
            max++;
        } 
    }    
    printf("Values read in:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < max-1; ++i) 
    {
        printf("[%f,%f]\n", X[i], Y[i]);
    }
    free(X);
    free(Y);
    return 0;
}

double * safe_realloc_double(double * ptr, size_t size)
{
    double * p = realloc(ptr, size * sizeof (double));
    if (p == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Allocation error.\n");
        free(ptr);
    }
    return p;
}
```

**Old Answer**

You can use `fgets` to read your input line by line.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

double * safe_realloc_double(double * ptr, size_t size);

int main()
{
    double x, y;
    double *X = NULL, *Y = NULL;
    int max = 1, status, i;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    while (fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, stdin) != NULL)        
    {        
        status = sscanf(buffer, "[%lf,%lf]", &x, &y);
        if (status != 2)
        {
            printf("Wrong input.\n");
            free(X);
            free(Y);
            return 1;
        }
        X = safe_realloc_double(X, max);
        Y = safe_realloc_double(Y, max);
        if (X == NULL || Y == NULL)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            X[max-1]=x;
            Y[max-1]=y;
            max++;
        } 
    }    
    printf("Values read in:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < max-1; ++i) 
    {
        printf("[%f,%f]\n", X[i], Y[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

double * safe_realloc_double(double * ptr, size_t size)
{
    double * p = realloc(ptr, size * sizeof *ptr);
    if (p == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Allocation error.\n");
        free(ptr);
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: so you allocated an already allocated buffer, when max is 1.
which then cause a memory leak. I would prefer not to allocate X and Y, but to do X=NULL and Y=NULL before entering while loop to read x and y. That fixes the leak

Comment: @John good catch, thanks. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Side note: If `X = realloc (X ,max * sizeof(*X))` and `X` is now `NULL`, the _previous_ `X` value is lost, but should be freed by the user.  Same for `Y`.

Comment: @Tom Fenech Not to cause much mischief with `realloc()` thing, but `if (tempX == NULL || tempY == NULL)` is a problem too.  Think if only 1 of the 2 returned NULL.  Likely should handle X, Y separately.  In any case, this takes away from the OP's main issue.

Comment: @chux I've addressed your concern.

Comment: @John I appreciate that the initial `malloc` was redundant but I don't think that it would cause a memory leak. What makes you think that?

Comment: @TomFenech I was wrong, and you are correct. I didn't check it via the valgrind program. I am going to edit my comment about the memory leak.

But anyways, putting a free(X), and free(Y) before exiting the program is a better way of stopping the application.

Comment: Will this really work if there are multiple inputs in one line? E.g. if the user enters [1,1] [20,20] in one line, will there be two elements in the X array and two elements in the Y array? I think this is what the OP wanted.

Comment: @jkottnauer No it doesn't, I mistakenly assumed that the input would be one per line. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by

```
if (status != EOF)
        while (fgetc(stdin)!=' ') {}
```

I'd use something on the line of

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int status;
    double x, y;
    while (!feof(stdin) && (status = scanf(" [ %lf , %lf ]", &x, &y)) == 2) {
        printf("%f:%f\n", x, y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

see the spaces in the format string, they will eat all white space input at that place of the input without mandating there is some.

Note that it is customary to reallocate with a geometric progression (factor 1.5 and 2 are common) in order to avoid a quadratic behaviour.

Comment: Please remove the feof() it is useless and gives the OP the _illusion_ that it makes any sense here, which it does not.

Comment: @wildplasser, it is not redundant on Linux nor Solaris and a previous question shows that the OP is using Linux in a way that he already hit the bug.

Comment: @AProgrammer the space in front of `%lf` is not needed.  OP's "[%lf,%lf]" will perform the same as `"[ %lf, %lf]"`.

Comment: @chux, I tend to forget when it is needed and when it isn't and thus I avoid the question; I also prefer stylistically the symmetry of `" [ %lf , %lf ]"` to `" [%lf ,%lf ]"` which has the space at the wrong side of the coma.